# Analogy to explain why the light "can't be pushed"

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, inertial-frames, observers

I'm in constant search of day-life analogies to explain/understand counterintuitive physical facts. It helps me, and I hope it breaks the ice for others to get into physics. What I'm interested here is whether an analogy is well grounded or, on the contrary, there is no relationship with the actual phenomena.

If you throw a stone from a moving train in the moving direction, the speed of the stone is the train's speed plus the speed you give to the stone.

That's not the case for light. The speed of the train does not adds up to the speed of light.
Now the analogy:

> If a dragonfly touches for an instant the surface of still water, the speed of the wave on the water is the same without regard if the dragonfly is stopped or flying when it touches the surface.

Is this simplification well founded?

Thanks.

**EDIT**
Recall that in the analogy: the water is the electromagnetic field.
And the analogy tries to put forward the fact that switching on a lamp is something like "touching" a different medium (electromagnetic) from a mechanical (so to say) medium. And because the mediums are different in nature, energy (at least for this case --switching on a lamp) can't be conveyed from one to the other.

Furthermore, against the objection in the answers that a moving  dragonfly would measure a water-wave speed different than a dragonfly at rest, I think time dilation hasn't been considered, which actually makes to get the same speed measurement.

In fact, once you have stablished that light can't be pushed (so that its speed is constant) one can fall back on the well know diagram to show why time is different for reference frames moving at different speeds.

[image]

Comment: Your EDIT section feels weird to me. The speed of light has nothing to with the hypothesis that supposedly "energy cannot be transferred from the mechanical medium to the electromagnetic medium" ... first: there is NO electromagnetic medium. second: I do not know what you imply with talking about a lamp, but remember that the wire inside a common (old school) light bulb is a hot black-body radiator, and that the light you see from it actually arises from kinetic energy of elementary constituents of the wire, which is converted to energy of EM-radiation, mostly at infrared wavelengths.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this simplification well founded?

No. The surface waves on the water in your analogy travel through a physical medium, and their speed is fixed in relation to that medium. Suppose there were two different dragonflies skimming over the pond at different speeds. If each dragonfly would measure the speed of the wave with respect to their own frame of reference, they would measure different numbers.

That's not how it works with light. If you were in a spaceship, and you measured the speed of a laser beam that was passing beside you, you would observe it to be moving at the speed of light. Meanwhile, If I too was in a space ship, and if I were flying away from you, parallel to the beam, I could make the same measurement, and I would get the same result. The laser beam would be passing me at the speed of light.

It wouldn't matter how fast I was going. If I was receding from you at 80% of the speed of light (from your point of view), I still would measure the beam passing me at the speed of light, and if somebody else was receding from me in the same direction at 80% of the speed of light (from *my* point of view,) then they too would observe that the beam was passing them at the speed of light.

Comment: @Koschi and Solomon, but if the dragonfly/train in motion measures the speed of the wave in the pond, then because time is slower for them they will get the same result for speed of light that a stopped observer gets. (Maybe we'll need a new analogy to explain time dilation, but the original (you can't push the light) is not wrong after all).

Answer (score 2):

It does not hold.

Maybe bringing together your thoughts about water and the typical train from SR:
Consider you would have a large pool with you on a moving train (could be a waggon from the movie 'Snowpiercer'). If you perturb the water on that (moving) train, you see the water waves moving at some speed, and this is regardless of the speed of anything (e.g. dragonfly) that hit the surface, you are correct on this.
But an observer outside the train, standing still on the surface, observing the wave in the pool on the moving train would observe a different speed of the wave with respect to earth's surface as you measured with respect to the train... he would have to add the speed of the train to the speed of the wave w.r.t to the pool.
If the water would be outside, on a pool that is not on the train, and you perturb it from the train, YOU and everybody else on the train would think the wave is slower, having subtracted the speed of the train. (Assuming you observe a wave that has the same direction as the train.)

All of this is no analogy to the fact that for electromagnetic waves, everybody measures the same speed, no matter where one is and who 'causes' the electromagnetic wave.

Comment: "... different...  as you measured with respect to the train. " **But time goes slowly in the train** (with respect to the observer at rest).

Comment: @cibercitizen1 I do not understand, why you take time dilation into the analogy. (in this comment here and in the other answer and your edit of the the question) Time dilation can be seen as *consequence* of the law that the speed of light is a constant in all reference frames. Therefore it is weird to expand the analogy of water waves by saying sth. like "they would measure the same speed of the water waves if time dilation would be taken into account..." And how exactly would that work, considering how slow water waves and trains usually are compared to the speed of light?

Answer (score 1):

In one aspect the analogy holds, but in others it does not.

If we imagine we are observers stationary with respect to the pond, then the analogy reflects the fact that we see the ripples moving at the same speed regardless of how fast their source (the dragonfly) was moving.

However, in other respects the analogy is completely misleading. The speed of the ripples as observed by the dragonfly depends upon the dragonfly's speed, which is not true of light.

The speed of the ripples will be less in the direction of the dragonfly's motion and greater in the opposite direction, which is not true of light.

Any two fish moving relative to each other in the pond would observe the ripples moving at different speeds, which is not true of light.

The water is a medium which provides a reference for defining motion in an absolute sense, which is not possible in reality.

So in summary the analogy works only in a limited sense, and suggests misleading connotations in others.

Comment: Maybe the problem in the analogy is that light appears to advance in one direction, not in all directions like water waves. Just consider that the fishes can only see one radial slice of the wave, and that if they are moving, time goes slow for them.

Comment: Also, what I consider crucial is the fact that energy (kinetical) from a mechanical medium can't be transferred to the electromagnetic medium.